# Formatting x-axis of discrete data in pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I have a list of tuples that I want to plot. The tuples contain the number of times a word appears in a text collection and the number of words that appear this number of times.

```
 freq = [(k, len(list(v))) for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(coll.values()))]
plt.bar(range(len(freq)), [val[1] for val in freq])
plt.xticks(range(len(freq)), [val[0] for val in freq])
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.xlabel('Times a word appears in the collection',labelpad=1)
plt.ylabel('Number of words appearing x times')
plt.show()
```

I could provide the whole script but I think it's not needed.  The plot I'm getting is this: [image]

Most of the words appear only one time, with frequency meaning less words. The 182 is the word "the" for example. Obviously this is an ugly and awkward plot. My question is how I can get the x-axis to appear more informative. Scaling the data with `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()` is futile as most observations turn negative. Should I group with `np.arange()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it though, I used `log=True` to scale the y-axis and this is a better result I think.

[image]